# How do i filter a list of object and return that particular filtered object in Java 8

Tags: java

I am trying to get a filtered object through a **stream** api.

I have a list of **VendorAddress** , where a single address is a primary address. Here I am trying to filter that address and want it to return a **VendorAddress** object.

See below code:

```
 vendorAddressList.stream().filter(vendorAddressObj-> vendorAddressObj.isPrimary())
```

What should I do to get the filtered **VendorAddress** object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There may be multiple objects that pass the filter, or none. What should the output be in these cases?

Comment: you can use the findFirst method of the stream (if you're only expecting one result), it will return you an Optional object

Comment: @Eran if there is none then it should return null that would be ok.

Comment: why not just `.collect(Collectors.toList())` and check if it is empty?

Comment: Try using "findFirst()"
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--
It would be also good to use Optional.ofNullable()

Comment: @JackFlamp it is again going to return a list of object, not that particular object

Comment: ok, I see now that findFirst (or findAny) is a better option. It returns an optional. use that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`findAny`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--) terminal method:

```
Optional<VendorAddress> maybeAnAddress = vendorAddressList
        .stream()
        .filter(VendorAddress::isPrimary) // Note: I used a method reference here.
        .findAny();
VendorAddress primaryAddress = maybeAnAddress.orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are dozen ways to achieve that you want. For instance, you can grab first matched element like this

```
Optional<VendorAddress> result = vendorAddressList.stream()
    .filter(vendorAddressObj-> vendorAddressObj.isPrimary()).findFirst();
```

or any matched

```
Optional<VendorAddress> result = vendorAddressList.stream()
    .filter(vendorAddressObj-> vendorAddressObj.isPrimary()).findAny();
```

In case if you're want all matched elements

```
List<VendorAddress> result = vendorAddressList.stream()
    .filter(vendorAddressObj-> vendorAddressObj.isPrimary()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and many more...
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use findFirst and either get (if you want an exception when not found) or orElse(null) (if you want null when not found).

Like this

```
VendorAddress address =  vendorAddressList.stream()
    .filter(vendorAddressObj-> vendorAddressObj.isPrimary())
    .findFirst() //Can be changed to findAny()
    .orElse(null); //Can be changed to get()
```

This will return the first found instance in your list. If you are sure you only have one, or does not care that it strictly returns the same (first) element every time, you can use findAny() instead of findFirst() for better performance.